# How to run a task on yocto custom board on boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, yocto-project

I have a custom linux board and i'm trying to run a task in background on boot. Task runs fine in background with **setsid** command but throws an error for **nohup** and **&**.

But, I'm unable to run that task during startup. There's no **rc.local** and no **systemctl**. Also, I can't use **apt-get**. Is there a way to run my task on boot?

Here's how I have tried:

1) under root, I created a file called **test.sh** in **/etc/init.d** with contents -

```
#!/bin/sh
setsid /home/root/myfile /home/root/myfile.conf > /dev/null 2>&1 &
exit 0
```

2) `chmod +x test.sh`

3) `update-rc.d test.sh start 85 5 .`

4)reboot the board and check `ps x`.  Wasn't able to find it in here.

**EDIT :** For people asking me to list out what i have - I know only about rc.local and systemd. Well, also upstart. and since i have none, I'm not sure what more to show.

```
cat /etc/os-release    

ID="poky"                                                                       
NAME="Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro)"                                    
VERSION="2.4.2 (rocko)"                                                         
VERSION_ID="2.4.2"                                                              
PRETTY_NAME="Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 2.4.2 (rocko)"
```

Comment: *"There's no **rc.local** and no **systemctl**."* -- Instead of a (negative) description of what you do not have, provide a description of what you do have.

Comment: @sawdust: I've already listed what i've done and what i have. Please go through it once. Also, there's this edit part now.

Comment: Apparently you have SystemV initialization.  Your **test.sh** file in **/etc/init.d** is missing the `INIT INFO` header.  See the man page for **insserv(8)**.  Your use of the **update-rc.d** command is malformed.  Check its man page.

Comment: Thanks man. But it still doesn't work.